# ImageIO garbage temp files are not deleted after work is done

Tags: scala, javax.imageio

I am using ImageIO to convert files from JBIG2 to JPEG, everything works fine but the temp files that ImageIO creates are not being deleted, and are stuck in the temp folder.

for example: `imageio1278573787994972734.tmp`

- Running GC doesn't help
- Dispose on the image reader doesn't help
- disabling Cache doesnt help

This is going to work very hard and i don't want to run out of disk space.

Any ideas how to make him delete these temp files once its done?

Thanks.

Here is the code:

> ```
> def convertJBig2ToJpeg(j2bigFile: File) : Try[File] = Try {
> import java.io._
> import net.java.truecommons.shed.ResourceLoan._
> loan (new FileInputStream(j2bigFile)) to { inputStream =>
>   val disf = new DefaultInputStreamFactory()
>   val imageInputStream = disf.getInputStream(inputStream)
>   val imageReader = new JBIG2ImageReader(new JBIG2ImageReaderSpi())
>   imageReader.setInput(imageInputStream)
>   val param = imageReader.getDefaultReadParam
>   val bufferedImage = imageReader.read(0, param)
>   val newFilePath = j2bigFile.getParent + "/" + j2bigFile.getName.split('.')(0) + "." + MimeType.postfixValue(JPG)
>   val newFile = new File(newFilePath)
>   try {
>     ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, MimeType.postfixValue(JPG), newFile)
>   }catch {
>     case e: Throwable =>
>       Files.deleteIfExists(newFile.toPath)
>       throw e
>   }
>   newFile
> }}
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when you do not dispose the resources properly after reading and writing.

Follow this disposing strategy to get rid of problems

This is the Java syntax.

disposing reader

```
if(imageReader.getInput() != null && imageReader.getInput() instanceof ImageInputStream)            
  ((ImageInputStream)imageReader.getInput()).close();
imageReader.dispose();
```

disposing writer

```
try {
     imageWriter.setOutput(out);
     imageWriter.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), iwp);
     out.flush();
 } catch(IOException e) {                        
     imageWriter.abort();                    
     throw e;
 } finally {
     try {                           
         out.close();                            
     } catch(Exception inner) {                              
     }
     imageWriter.dispose();
 }
```

above code in Scala

```
try {
     imageWriter.setOutput(out)
     imageWriter.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), iwp)
     out.flush()
 } catch { 
   case e: IOException =>                        
     imageWriter.abort()                    
     throw e
   case _ => if (imageWriter != null) imageWriter.abort()
 } finally {
     try {                           
         out.close()                         
     } catch {
       case _ =>                              
     }
     imageWriter.dispose()
 }
```

for more info visit [this blog](http://info.michael-simons.eu/2012/01/25/the-dangers-of-javas-imageio/) which explains the same